# Disable all style attributes for all elements

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm looking for HTML 4 compliance with CKEditor since we're using htmLawed on the back end to filter bad JS/CSS/HTML from getting into our database. So far, we've set up htmLawed to remove any HTML elements with the "style" attribute. This works perfectly for core styles and font size/color, as exemplified by my config here:

```
    coreStyles_bold      : { element: 'b' },
    coreStyles_italic    : { element: 'i' },
    coreStyles_underline : { element: 'u' },
    coreStyles_strike    : { element: 'strike' },
    fontSize_style       :
    {
        element    : 'font',
        attributes : { 'size': '#(size)' }
    },
    colorButton_foreStyle :
    {
        element    : 'font',
        attributes : { 'color': '#(color)' }
    },
    colorButton_backStyle:
    {
        element : 'font',
        styles  : { 'background-color': '#(color)' }
    }
```

The problem I'm having is with the indent. When I have a list element (such as "ul" or "ol") that I try to indent, CKEditor renders HTML as shown below, which is sent to the server. HtmLawed then strips out the style attribute from the ul element and renders the list as not indented when I display it on the front end.

```
<ul style="margin-left: 40px;">
<li>Some Text Here</li>
</ul>
```

My question is...how do I prevent all elements from setting any kind of style attribute? I would like CKEditor to use pure HTML to do the formatting, as we're only allowing a limited set of formatting options. I would really like to see HTML produced by CKEditor that looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Some Text Here</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate things - indent plugin should be able to indet only lists (changing their structure, not adding left margin), not blocks. At this moment one plugin does two jobs, what does not make sense. Patch for this will be released in about a month - https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10027.

Although, even now it is possible to configure indent to use classes rather than styles - see the [`config.indentClasses`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-indentClasses) option.

Comment: I can't use classes. This is because we're using the output of CKEditor to display on the front end as well as in a PDF (using a PHP PDF library). The PDF library is not aware of these classes.